# Flex 4.6 Center Image

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, actionscript

I am using Adobe Flex 4.6 and I have this image:

```
<mx:Image source="assets/logo.png" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"></mx:Image>
```

The image appears, but it does not center horizontal or vertical, how Do I center this image?

I have also tried the following:

```
<mx:Canvas width="100%">
        <mx:HBox horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0">
            <mx:Image source="assets/logo.png" horizontalAlign="center" verticalAlign="middle"></mx:Image>
        </mx:HBox>
    </mx:Canvas>
```

Still nothing, my image wont center

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me

```
<s:Group width="100%" height="100%">
        <s:layout>
            <s:VerticalLayout
                verticalAlign="middle"
                horizontalAlign="center"/>
        </s:layout>
        <s:BitmapImage source="@Embed(source='assets/logo.png')" />

    </s:Group>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the horizontalCenter and VerticalCenter properties in the image tag as below

```
<mx:Image source="assets/logo.png" horizontalCenter="0" verticalCenter="0"></mx:Image>
```

It is working fine for me.

Comment: It will work. If you have some container which is having this image, then set the height and width of that container to 100%